# regex get part of the link

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink

https://www.example.com/uk/This-Part-I-Need-To-Get/F1ST2/sometext/

need to get "This-Part-I-Need-To-Get", with "-" symbols and capital letters at the wordstart.
All I managed to do is "/([A-Z-])\w+/g", that returns

"This" "-Part" "-I" "-Need" "-To" "-Get" "F1ST2", but I don`t need "F1ST2".
How should I do it?

Comment: Perhaps, [`/\w+(?:-\w+)+/`](https://regex101.com/r/qoIm2I/1). But if other parts of the path contain `-`, there might be unwanted results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on URL format, but at this point:

```js
var url = 'https://www.example.com/uk/This-Part-I-Need-To-Get/F1ST2/sometext/';
console.log(url.split('/')[4])
```

Comment: The fastest way, definitely

Answer (score 0):

As @MichałSałaciński said, you should consider using `split` function.

BTW, if you wan't to use regular expressions, then this one will work if url format does not change : `[^\/]+(?=(?:\/\w+){2}\/)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEeTpC/1)

```js
var re = /[^\/]+(?=(?:\/\w+){2}\/)/
var url = "https://www.example.com/uk/This-Part-I-Need-To-Get/F1ST2/sometext/"

if(re.test(url)) {
  // URL match regex pattern, we can safely get full match
  var value = re.exec(url)[0];
  console.log(value);
}
```

**Explanation**

`[^\/]+` Any character but a slash *n* times

`(?=...)` Followed by

`(?:\/\w+){2}\/` a slash and any word character (2 times) then a slash

**Solution 2**

This one also works using captured group 1: `:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mXy0Dn/1/)

```js
var re = /:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/;
var url = "https://www.example.com/uk/This-Part-I-Need-To-Get/F1ST2/sometext/";

if(re.test(url)) {
  // URL match regex pattern, we can safely get group 1 value
  var value = re.exec(url)[1];
  console.log(value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

`/([A-Z][a-z]|-[A-Z]|-[A-Z][a-z]-|-[A-Z]-)\w+/g`

Here is a **SNIPPET**

```js
var url = 'https://www.example.com/uk/This-Part-I-Need-To-Get/F1ST2/sometext/';
console.log(url.match(/([A-Z][a-z]|-[A-Z]|-[A-Z][a-z]-|-[A-Z]-)\w+/g).join(''))
```